# Code not compiling

Tags: c, data-structures

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void insert(int *,int);

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    int tree[1000];

    memset(tree,'\0',1000);
    int i=1;

    while (!argv[i])
    {   
        insert(tree,atoi(argv[i]));
    }
    int depth=0;
    printf("Enter depth");
    scanf("%d",&depth);

    int x=pow(2,depth);
    int y=2x-1;
    int count=0;
    for(;x<=y;x++)
    {
        if((tree[x]!=NULL) && (tree[2x+1]==NULL) && (tree[2x]==NULL))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("Number of leaf nodes is %d", count);
}

void insert(int *tree,int gmail)
{
    int i=1;

    if(tree[i]==NULL)
    {
        tree[i]=gmail;
    }
    else
    {
        if(gmail>tree[i])
        {
            insert(tree[2i+1],gmail);
        }
        else
            insert(tree[2i],gmail);
    }
}
```

Comment: Format your code such that it is at least readable!

Comment: Please: be polite · tell us what you need. Do not post only code.

Comment: in the function insert it says that array subscript is not an integer

Comment: and the other error is in the line with power function. error is invalid suffix "x" on integer constant

Comment: I don't usually downvote, but this question borders on troublesome. People want to help, but you're expected to put in a reasonable effort yourself.

Comment: @David, I think he has not much answers to accept, most of his questions were closed...

Comment: @Jens: He still has quite a few that aren't, though...

Answer (score 4):

You can't just write this:

```
insert(tree[2i+1],gmail);
```

You need to provide the multiplication operation explicitly, ie: `[2*i+1]` or `[2*i]`.

Also, as `tree[2*i0]` is an `int`, not an `int*`, you'll need it's address:

```
insert(&(tree[2*i+1]),gmail);
```

and:

```
insert(&(tree[2*i]),gmail);
```

Alternatively, you could use:

```
insert(tree + (2*i), gmail);
```

The other error is the `pow` call.  [pow](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/) returns a double value, not int, so you'll need to cast back to an int:

```
 int x = (int) pow(2.0, depth);
```

Comment: oh crap.. thanks buddy.... and what about that power function?

Comment: @user420878 for the power function use `Math.pow` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/

Comment: And just to add on to this, use `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Comment: @user420878: Missed that in your comments, since there was no mention in the question itself.  I added it in my answer.

Comment: @Argote: `Math.pow(..)` ?? ;-)

Comment: @Argote: This is C, not C++. It's just called pow.

Answer (score 1):

Once you do get it to compile, you'll want to fix this:

```
while (!argv[i])
{   
    insert(tree,atoi(argv[i]));
}
```

This will either 1) not execute at all, or 2) give an infinite loop. also, `if (!argv[1])` is equivalent to `if (argv[i] == NULL)`, so you're trying to read a value if an only if no value is present to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<math.h> 
void insert(int *,int); 
int main(int argc, char argv[]) 
{
   int tree[1000];    
   memset(tree,'\0',1000);    
   int i=1;      
   while (!argv[i])     
   {    
       insert(tree,atoi(argv[i]));   
   }    
   int depth=0;  
   printf("Enter depth");  
   scanf("%d",&depth);     
   int x=pow(2.0,depth); 
   int y=2*x-1;    
   int count=0;
   for(;x<=y;x++)
   {
       if((tree[x]!=NULL) && (tree[2*x+1]==NULL) && (tree[2*x]==NULL))   
       {
           count++;   
       }
   }
   printf("Number of leaf nodes is %d", count);
```

}

```
void insert(int *tree,int gmail)
{
   int i=1;
   if(tree[i]==NULL)
   {
       tree[i]=gmail;    
   }
   else 
   {
      if(gmail>tree[i])     
      {
          insert(tree,tree[2*i+1]);     
      }
      else
          insert(tree,tree[2*i]);   
  }
```

}

this code has work,only in my compiler the memset function has not recognize
what is this function ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `2i` and `2x` as a subscript into an array.  This is not valid the way you are using it.  Try replacing occurrences of `2i` with `2 * i` and `2x` with `2 * x`.

Answer (score 0):

`2i+1` isn't valid. try `(2*i) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

`2i` and `2x` are not valid expressions, you should put `2*i` and `2*x`!

Next time post the line where it doesn't compile and some explanations, it will be more easy to read..